# Troubles with Swing Timer and ActionEvents

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, date, timer

I'm trying to get a JLabel to display the date and update every second. To do this I'm using Swing's Timer class and implementing my own class called DateTimer. DateTimer is also an ActionListener.

This is DateTimer:

```
public class DateTimer implements ActionListener {
    private int delay;
    private JLabel label;
    private Calendar cal;

    public DateTimer(int delay, JLabel label) {
        this.delay = delay;
        this.label = label;

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        new Timer(this.delay, this).start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.label.setText(this.cal.getTime().toString());
    }

}
```

I call this from somewhere else in my code like this:

```
new DateTimer(1000, this.label);
```

I get the date to display once, then it doesn't ever update.

I'm new to Java GUIs and handling actions so please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`java.util.Calendar.getInstance()` returns an object representing the current date and time *at the time it is created*. It doesn't update automatically as you are assuming.

Comment: +1, instead he'll probably want to do the following `Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()`

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks to both of you. I'm using Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()